Visual Studio Android emulator API 35 crash on startup
Suddenly Android emulator started crashing for devices with API 35. The only thing I did was updating the emulator, update was forced by the Visual Studio.
Here is the error:
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): AndroidVirtualizationFramework
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Admin\.android\avd\..\avd
exus_10_-_api_35.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=nexus_10_-_api_35'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=438fc447-0f17-40f9-b346-9cf3560601bc'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING | Your GPU 'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620' has driver version 1.3.215, and cannot support Vulkan properly on windows. Please update your GPU Driver.
netsimd I 12-04 09:32:39.621 daemon\src\rust_main.rs:98 - netsim artifacts path: "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
etsimd"
netsimd I 12-04 09:32:39.622 daemon\src\rust_main.rs:101 - NetsimdArgs {
    fd_startup_str: None,
    no_cli_ui: true,
    no_web_ui: true,
    pcap: false,
    disable_address_reuse: false,
    hci_port: None,
    connector_instance: None,
    instance: None,
    logtostderr: false,
    dev: false,
    disable_wifi_p2p: false,
    rust_grpc: false,
    vsock: None,
    config: None,
    host_dns: Some(
        "192.168.8.1",
    ),
    http_proxy: None,
    test_beacons: false,
    no_test_beacons: false,
    no_shutdown: false,
    verbose: false,
    version: false,
}
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
WARNING | ** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio **
WARNING | Device 'cache' does not have the requested snapshot 'default_boot'
WARNING | Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'

Some of these errors make no sense, for example my emulator is already up to date, and my GPU drivers are also already up to date. Internet suggests corrupted installation, so I have reinstalled API 35 but it changed nothing.
